# Java Enum getDeclaringClass vs getClass

Tags: java, enums

The docs for the Java Enum class state the following about `getDeclaringClass`:

> Returns the Class object corresponding
>   to this enum constant's enum type. Two
>   enum constants e1 and e2 are of the
>   same enum type if and only if
>   e1.getDeclaringClass() ==
>   e2.getDeclaringClass(). (The value
>   returned by this method may differ
>   from the one returned by the
>   Object.getClass() method for enum
>   constants with constant-specific class
>   bodies.)

I don't understand when `getClass` and `getDeclaringClass` are different. Can someone provide an example along with an explanation?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Java enum values are permitted to have value-specific class bodies, e.g. (and I hope this syntax is correct...)

```
public enum MyEnum {

   A {
       void doSomething() { ... }
   },


   B {
       void doSomethingElse() { ... }
   };
}
```

This will generate inner classes representing the class bodies for `A` and `B`. These inner classes will be subclasses of `MyEnum`.

`MyEnum.A.getClass()` will return the anonymous class representing `A`'s class body, which may not be what you want.

`MyEnum.A.getDeclaringClass()`, on the other hand, will return the `Class` object representing `MyEnum`.

For simple enums (i.e. ones without constant-specific class bodies), `getClass()` and `getDeclaringClass()` return the same thing.