# Is it better to use class.isEnum() or instanceof Enum?

Tags: java, enums

I have an object. I want to check to see if it is of type enum. There are two ways to do this.

```
object.getClass().isEnum()
```

or

```
object instanceof Enum
```

Is one better?

Comment: By "better," do you mean "easier to read," "runs faster," etc.?

Comment: @templatetypedef Mostly performance then easier to read.

Comment: If you need to determine if an object is an Enum, then the question you should be asking is "Why am I using this terrible design".

Comment: @DwB I don't think you can assume what I am doing before you make that comment? I am creating a formatter which needs to know what type of object it is to format. If there is a better way to format(object) then I am all ears.

Comment: Its already coming from format(list) so I lose the type because erasure.

Comment: If you're going to use `isEnum()` you should note that when it comes to enums it is advised to use `getDeclaringClass()` instead of `getClass()` especially when you want to test whether it is an enum or not. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758660/java-enum-getdeclaringclass-vs-getclass?rq=1)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In my opinion `object instanceof Enum` is better for several reasons:

- It is very obvious what is asked here: "is this an enum"?
- It doesn't risk a `NullPointerException` (if `object` is `null`, it will just evaluate to `false`)
- It's shorter.

The only reason I'd see for using `isEnum()` would be if I only have access to the `Class` object and not to a concrete instance.

Comment: +1 about NPE. I am doing that right now in a loop and wasn't sure if it would matter

Comment: As far as performance, `instanceof` works faster too (it varies depending on the class being tested, but for all of my tests has been at least 33% faster than `isEnum`, fastest has been about 450% faster). isEnum: 2691826
instanceof: 658774

Comment: @ty1824 - awesome. Stats are the exact thing I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the latter (`object instanceof Enum`) because the former may not work with enum constants with constant-specific class bodies.

For example, for this enum type:

```java
enum MyEnum {
    FOO { }
}
```

The expression `MyEnum.FOO.getClass().isEnum()` returns `false`.

If you want to check if an object is a enum constant without `instanceof Enum`, you have to use this (much more complicated) expression:

```java
static boolean isEnum(Object obj) {
    Class<?> cls = obj.getClass();
    Class<?> superCls = cls.getSuperclass();
    // Be careful, Object.class.getSuperclass() returns null
    return cls.isEnum() || (superCls != null && superCls.isEnum());
}
```