# How can I get the enum class from a variable?

Tags: java

Best explained in code.

I have something like this

```
public enum MyEnum implements MyEnumInterface { 
   A,
   B,
   C
}

public enum MyOtherEnum implements MyEnumInterface { 
   AA,
   BB,
   CC
}
```

and somewhere else

```
public void doSomething(MyEnumInterface anEnum, ... ) {
   ... 
   // doSomething 
   ... 
}
```

I would like to find out what class anEnum comes from (e.g. MyEnum or MyOtherEnum).

How can I do that? (without doing an instanceof check for all possible implementations :) )

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Use polymorphism. Whatever it is you are needing to do, put it on the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by accessing its class object:

```
System.out.println(anEnum.getDeclaringClass().getName());
```

Note that [`getDeclaringClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#getDeclaringClass()) is critically different from `getClass()` when each value has a custom class body. *[More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758660/java-enum-getdeclaringclass-vs-getclass)*

Comment: That works, thanks for confirming! I had tried this before and for some reason it didn't work out, but I think I just did something stupid that time.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it helped. And thank you for big green checkmark and up-vote!  :)

Comment: -1 for using getClass and not getDeclaringClass, which will break in weird ways on enums that declare constant specific methods.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `.getDeclaringClass()` on the enum value to get the class. But I think you are in search of the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

```
public class Example implements Visitor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example example = new Example();
        example.doSomething(MyEnum.A);
        example.doSomething(MyOtherEnum.BB);
    }

    public void doSomething(MyEnumInterface anEnum) {
        anEnum.visit(this);
    }

    @Override public void visit(MyEnum my) {
        System.out.println("MyEnum: " + my);
    }

    @Override public void visit(MyOtherEnum my) {
        System.out.println("MyOtherEnum: " + my);
    }
}

interface Visitor {

    public void visit(MyEnum my);

    public void visit(MyOtherEnum my);
}

interface MyEnumInterface {
    public void visit(Visitor visitor);
}

enum MyEnum implements MyEnumInterface { 
    A,
    B,
    C;

    @Override public void visit(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
 }

 enum MyOtherEnum implements MyEnumInterface { 
    AA,
    BB,
    CC;

    @Override public void visit(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

This is the answer to your comment:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(MyEnum.A.getDeclaringClass());
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
class MyEnum
```

Comment: I can't do anEnum.getDeclaringClass(); I can do anEnum.getClass().getDeclaringClass(), but that does not ( necessarily) return MyEnum etc. If your enum declaration is itself in another class, it will return that.

Comment: And now you may copy-paste the whole Example, which shows you how and that it works, as described.

Answer (score 1):

Enums are also classes so use

```
if(anEnum instanceof MyEnum) {...}
```

and

`if(anEnum instanceof MyOtherEnum) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the instanceof operator to decide what type the object is