# Why Java Enum need to check class and declaringClass in compareTo method

Tags: java, enums

Type parameter `E` in Enum is defined as `<E extends Enum<E>>`. So why in Enum implementation source [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Enum.java#165), we still need to check `getClass()` and `getDeclaringClass()` in `compareTo` method? I don't think compiler can pass when I set a different enum type object in `compareTo`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It covers the case of comparing raw types and [values obtained via unsafe / unchecked casts and conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462750/why-java-enum-need-to-check-class-and-declaringclass-in-compareto-method/42462851?noredirect=1#comment72068990_42462851) (such as `Comparable`, or `Object a`):

```
static enum Fruit { Apple, Orange, Banana };
static enum Animal { Cat, Dog, Horse };

public static final void main (String[] args) throws Exception {   
    Enum f = Fruit.Apple;
    Enum a = Animal.Cat;
    f.compareTo(a);
}
```

There, `compareTo` would fail with a `ClassCastException` at the explicit `getDeclaringClass` comparison, as it would pass the first explicit cast (`Enum other = (Enum)o`) with no issue.

As for comparing `getClass`, it's tagged as an "optimization" in that source. The reason this is an optimization is that if the [value classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5758708/616460) are the same, then they're *definitely* from the same enum, and so there's no need to call the slightly more expensive [`getDeclaringClass`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Enum.java#Enum.getDeclaringClass%28%29). Since the vast majority of enums are likely simple enums (no value class bodies), it's optimized for that case.

Comment: It is not just raw types.  It also applies if you declare `f` and `a` to have type `Object`.

Comment: @StephenC Only if `a` is `Object`. If `f` is `Object` then you would not have `f.compareTo` available. Also the exception stack trace is actually slightly different for an `Enum` vs `Object` type for `a`, so I need to think about how to clearly formulate that in words before I add a mention of `Object` to this answer.

Comment: If you cast `f` to `Comparable<?>` you do.  (OK `Object` was the wrong choice ... my bad.)  Also, consider `Enum<?>` which technically is not a raw type (see JLS 4.8).  But my point is that "raw types" are not the only reason for this.

Comment: @StephenC If `f` was `Comparable<?>`, how would `f.compareTo(a);` compile?

Comment: @StephenC It'd have to be `Comparable`, not `Comparable<?>`, as neither `Enum<?>` nor `Comparable<?>` would compile. But I do see what you're saying even though I'm being pedantic about types. `Comparable` leads to the same slightly different stack trace as `Object` so, I will definitely add the additional info to the answer, but not until I'm sure what I write is 100% correct.

Comment: Casting `f` to `Comparable<?>` and then to `Comparable<Enum<?>>` would work. Then there would be no rawtypes involved, just unchecked casts.

Comment: @JasonC - yes you are right about `Comparable` versus `Comparable<?>`.  Also `Enum` versus `Enum<?>`.   Using the `<?>` types causes the compiler to look for methods whose parameterized signature matches.  It fails because the compiler (correctly) infers that the types captured by the two `?` wildcards are not the same.

Comment: Maybe a better phrasing would be "raw types and values obtained via unsafe / unchecked casts and conversions".  With maybe a footnote to remind people it is unwise to ignore those compiler warnings ...

Comment: @StephenC [I cannot explain the stack trace difference I am seeing yet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464475/mysterious-line-in-stack-trace), although as an aside I have confirmed to my satisfaction that the `compareTo` logic definitely protects in the `Object`/`Comparable` case. That stack trace is the only reason I was questioning myself there, otherwise it would've been an easy add.

Answer (score 4):

It can, if you use `Enum` as a raw type. For instance in this program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Enum e = A.x; // All occurrences of E are erased to Enum
    e.compareTo(B.i); // B.i extends Enum, so this is fine
}   

enum A {x,y,z};
enum B {i,j,k};
```

Comment: `E` is not `Enum` here. If you tried to provide `Enum` as `E`, it wouldn't compile. There just isn't an `E`.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, I was trying to rephrase that. The idea was that the erasure of `compareTo(E)` is `compareTo(Enum)`.